# Raspberry pi B+ internal power supply ckt?

Tags: power-supply, dc, raspberry-pi, bjt, protection

I have just started to study about raspberry pi B+ ([data sheet](https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/introducing-the-raspberry-pi-model-b-plus-plus-differences-vs-model-b.pdf))

Can somebody explain the working of power supply circuit (individual component wise) starting from pg 14. How and why it is advantageous. I guess the implementation of a wildar current mirror in the diagram..

[image]

Comment: If you Google this, there are some folks that have already dissected this circuit, but at a high-level, that box uses a few discrete components to implement an 'ideal-diode' solution to protect against reverse polarity. Q3 is a PFET that will exhibit a much lower voltage drop than a diode ever would, and U14 is used as a current mirror to trigger the PFET when correct biased. If Vpin6 > Vpin5, Q3 is turned on and normal operation proceeds. If the opposite (reverse polarity), Q3 is turned off. A PFET generally has worse RDS(on) than an NFET, but no charge-pump is needed for a P.

Comment: A discussion about halfway down this page has some discussion of this circuit: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=81922&p=580050#p579707